# Map managed properties Path, OriginalPath to a custom property in SharePoint Online Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, crawled-property

We have a custom Content Type which we added to a SharePoint list in each site collection to save site metadata. Content Type has a url field named "Site URL" which just saves the site collection url. Now, when user searching for content the list item will show up and the url shows the list item display form url with ?ID=.

We like to map/prioritize the custom url property "SiteURL" to Path, OriginalPath managed properties, so actual site collection url maps to search result. But, it is not working that way. Properties mapped fine and below is the value for both.

ows_q_URLH_MSCProjectSiteURL, ClientUrl, Basic:11

Any ideas please suggest.

-Praveen.

Comment: Have you tested by creating new managed property? Also, if it is a site column, by default managed property will be created for it. Have you tried to see if that displays the result?

Comment: Hello @GoldiAgrawal. Yes I have waited quite some time to get the managed property shows up content. I also mapped managed property RefinableString19 to this custom property. I see the RefinableString19 is bring the data back. I will give more time to search crawl and see if it makes any sense. Now I have changed the mapping to include ows_MSCProjectSiteURL instead of ows_q_URLH_MSCProjectSiteURL

Comment: I had similar issue where it was showing updated index... The solution for that was to re-index the library where the column is used. Have you tried doing that already? In general, schema is picked in full crawl but since it is online, MS had recommended to reindex the list/library after adding the column and corresponding values in library/list.

Comment: I have tried all possible things to resolve this issue. But there is no resolution at the moment, I mapped the MSCProjectSiteURL to RefinableString19 mapped property and search is able to return the value as expected. Mapped the same to Path, OriginalPath and it don't reflect these values. Looks like Path, OriginalPath we cannot change.... Anyone clarify on this if this is true?

Comment: For now, I have created display template for the enterprise search results pages, for site search results pages still it is broken as the display templates don't work for modern SharePoint search result pages. Hope I will have some solution in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to change the item URL in the search result with the custom site column value?

If that’s the case, I recommend you map the site URL column as a custom managed property and edit the display template for the search result web part to use this custom managed property.

Reference: [How to display values from custom managed properties in classic search results - option 1 in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-resultsoption-1)

Comment: I am sorry. You might not read the question right. This is in SharePoint Online.